# Como hacer un trigger en SQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Al intentar hacer un trigger en mi base de datos, me salta error y no se porque puede ser:

```html
create trigger updateEstado 
after insert on reservas
for each row
begin
    update inventario set estado = "ocupado" where idEquipo = new.idEquipo;
end;
```

Me salta este error:

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 5

Adjunto script de la base de datos:

```html
create database if not exists reservaEquiposs;

create table if not exists users(
    nombre varchar(60) not null,
    apellido varchar(60) not null,
    codigo varchar(10) not null primary key,
    email varchar(30) not null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    role varchar(30) not null,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp
);

create table if not exists tipos(
    id varchar(255) not null,
    tipo varchar(60) not null primary key
);

create table if not exists equipos(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    tipo varchar(60) not null,
    marca varchar(50) not null,
    modelo varchar(255) not null,
    numSerie varchar(255) not null,
        FOREIGN KEY (tipo) references tipos(tipo) on update cascade on delete cascade
);

create table if not exists ubicaciones(
    id int not null,
    aula varchar(50) not null primary key
);

create table if not exists estados(
    id int not null,
    estado varchar(30) not null primary key
);

create table if not exists inventario(
    id int(200) not null auto_increment primary key,
    ubicacion varchar(50) not null,
    idEquipo int not null,
    descripcion varchar(100),
    estado varchar(30) not null,
        FOREIGN KEY (idEquipo) REFERENCES equipos(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
        FOREIGN KEY (ubicacion) REFERENCES ubicaciones(aula),
        FOREIGN KEY (estado) REFERENCES estados(estado)
);

create table if not exists reservas(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    codigoProfesor varchar(10) not null,
    idEquipo int not null,
    horaInicio datetime not null,
    horaFin datetime not null,
    fechaReserva date not null,
        FOREIGN KEY (codigoProfesor) REFERENCES users(codigo) on update cascade on delete cascade,
        FOREIGN KEY (idEquipo) REFERENCES equipos(id)
);
```

No se si las tablas tienen que estar relacionadas entre sí para poder crear un trigger, he estado buscando información y la sintaxis es correcta, pero no encuentro el porqué del error.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! es mysql.. ni php, ni laravel.. no sirven ni suman esas etiquetas..

Answer (score 0):

Como tienes instrucciones SQL dentro de la definición, el punto y coma rompe la instrucción de creación del trigger.

Tienes que cambiar el delimitador temporalmente. Algo como

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE UPDATE ON account
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
           IF NEW.amount < 0 THEN
               SET NEW.amount = 0;
           ELSEIF NEW.amount > 100 THEN
               SET NEW.amount = 100;
           END IF;
       END;//
mysql> delimiter ;
```

Comment: Perdona, pero no lo entiendo, ahora he quitado el ";" de la línea de update y me da error de sintaxis en end.

Comment: @Nadie es porque no estás leyendo con detenimiento qué es lo que está haciendo diferente. Y te lo estoy explicando en la respuesta, junto con un ejemplo completo